# How to limit string variable content to some define no bytes(i.e 6 bytes) after 6 bytes all the content should truncate?

Tags: c++, string

How to limit string variable  content to some define no bytes(i.e 6 bytes) after 6 bytes all the content should get truncate. for example lets say   string var="hello world" then o/p should be as "hello" and from 6th position all the content should get deleted. my approach is below but i am not able to delete so i have inserted space please help me to fix it. Thank you

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

void check_no_bytes(string);

int main() 
{
    string var[3];
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) 
    {
        getline(cin,var[i]);
        check_no_bytes(var[i]); 
    }
}

void check_no_bytes(string temp)
{
    int byte;

    if (temp.length()<5)
    {
        cout<<temp<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        for(byte=6;byte<=temp.length();byte++)
            temp[byte]=' ';// here i am inserting space but i want to delete all the contenet from 6th position?

        cout<<temp<<endl;
    }   
}
```

Comment: _This_ is how you are indenting your code? _Seriously???_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among the things wrong with the posted code:

- You're not including `<string>`, required for `std::string` per the standard.
- Your loop conditional is wrong. It iterates four times, not three, thereby invoking undefined behavior on the last iteration.
- The entire check function can be removed in favor of using `substr` on the line just-read:

Simplified, one such implementation would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string var[3];
    for (auto& s : var)
    {
        if (!std::getline(std::cin, s))
            break;
        std::cout << s.substr(0,6) << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Input**

```
12345678
123456
12
```

**Output**

```
123456
123456
12
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could call `string.substr(0, 5)` or, if you are just printing it, insert `\0` at position 6:

```
temp[6]='\0'
```

Comment: Is inserting a null-terminator in the middle of an std::string a defined behavior?

Comment: @awesomryi no i am not trying to print only i am trying limit space upto 6 bytes only and even NULL won't work as terminator here

Comment: @user4950013 Have you tried `cout << temp.substr(0, 6) << endl`?

Comment: @KABoissonneault yes it is defined.  The null, along with all the characters after it are retained in the string.

Comment: @IronMensan I was just wondering because of the O(1) complexity restriction for string::size(). That would mean implementations would be tempted to cache the size of the string, and messing with the string by inserting null-terminators might invalidate that cache

Comment: @KABoissonneault most implementations do cache the length and inserting a null doesn't change that length.  Inside a `std::string` a null character is just another character, it doesn't get special treatment like with a `char *` string.

Comment: @IronMensan Ah, right I forgot an `std::string` is only guaranteed to be null-terminated when you call `c_str` or `data`. Now I understand